# AWS-EC2 Can i upload Multiple website into one instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, instance

Is it possible to upload a multiple website to a one instance?
In amazon web service ec2.

Comment: Yes, you can do that. [1] https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FJZgwPpLvEw [2] https://www.brianshim.com/webtricks/host-multiple-sites-amazon-ec2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An Amazon EC2 instance is **just like any other computer**. You can load the operating system you desire (Windows, Linux) and the software you desire (eg [The Apache HTTP Server Project](https://httpd.apache.org/)).

Any configurations you wish to perform, such as loading multiple web sites, will depend upon the configuration of the web server software you install. The fact that it is an Amazon EC2 instance does not impact the way you would configure the web server.